# How to track path of stickman on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'd like to keep track of my stickman if I were to move it. However since my stickman is a bunch of lines and I believe the only way I can do this is by checking if certain pixels are of a certain color. Is there a better way of keep track of where my stickman is located on the canvas? I was told that if my stickman were an object my goal would be easier to reach. That said, I thought my stickman was of type object literal already. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

```
stickman = {head: [200, 200, 10,0,  2*Math.PI ],
body: [195, 210, 178, 250],
rightArm: [192,215,200,230,210,230],
leftArm: [192,215,178 ,222,178,230],
rightLeg: [178, 250,190,260,185,275,192, 275],
leftLeg: [178, 250, 168, 260, 155, 262,153, 268]
} ;

function costume1(){
context.strokeStyle =  "rgb(0,0,0)";
context.beginPath();
//head
context.arc(stickman.head[0], stickman.head[1], stickman.head[2], stickman.head[3], stickman.head[4]);
//body
context.moveTo(stickman.body[0],stickman.body[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.body[2],stickman.body[3]);

//right arm
context.moveTo(stickman.leftArm[0],stickman.leftArm[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftArm[2] ,stickman.leftArm[3]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftArm[4], stickman.leftArm[5]);

//left arm
context.moveTo(stickman.rightArm[0], stickman.rightArm[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightArm[2], stickman.rightArm[3]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightArm[4] , stickman.rightArm[5]);

//left leg
context.moveTo(stickman.rightLeg[0], stickman.rightLeg[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightLeg[2],stickman.rightLeg[3]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightLeg[4] , stickman.rightLeg[5]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightLeg[6], stickman.rightLeg[7]);


//right leg
context.moveTo(stickman.leftLeg[0], stickman.leftLeg[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftLeg[2], stickman.leftLeg[3]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftLeg[4], stickman.leftLeg[5]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftLeg[6] , stickman.leftLeg[7]);
context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Imagine a dot `*` (say the stickman body center). From that dot draw two legs. `/*\ ` Your mind-set should be: I need to move that dot position. The legs upper points should always be attached to that dot. That means that both upper points share the same position. That means that `leftLeg` upper point = stickman position. Than you need to move every leg. Create a moveLeg function. When the body moves (and updates accordingly the upper joints positions) you than reuse that position variable and just need to create the funny leg movements. I would need 700 lines to answer your question.

Comment: i don't get it. when you move it, wouldn't you also track it at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You are right - you have indeed created a stickman object. But if you want to move/track your stickman, it would be best to define the parts (the head, body, etc) in terms of a single, central point - for example you could use the centre of his head. Then to move/track the stickman, all you need to do is update those central points. The other parts of the stickman will then follow along.

Here is a demonstration of what I mean:

```
// set up a stickman, with a starting x and y
var Stickman = function(x, y) {
  this.update(x, y);
}

// anytime you need to know the new positions for the
// stickman, call .update(newCenterX, newCenterY)
Stickman.prototype.update = function(x, y) {
  this.centerX = x;
  this.centerY = y;
  this.head = [this.centerX, this.centerY, 10,0,  2*Math.PI ]
  this.body = [
    this.centerX-5,
    this.centerY+10,
    this.centerX-22,
    this.centerY+50
  ]
  this.rightArm = [ ];
  this.leftArm = [ ];
  // etc...
}

// here is how to make a new stickman
var man1 = new Stickman(200, 200);

// and move him!
console.log(man1.body);
man1.update(210, 200);
console.log(man1.body);`
```

Hope that helps! (I may not have got the offsets right :-) )

Comment: Super simple explanation! +1. Additionally OP could create move functions like `moveLeg : function() { /*hardcore stuff here*/ }` and than only inside that function move the actual leg where one point is relative to the `this.body` and the other points are relative to an inner angle loop which is relative the the old position... timing... animation...  .... and the story goes...

Answer (score 1):

You typically use `context.translate` to move your fixed-coordinate stickman to a different position.

```
// move the context origin 100px rightward
context.translate(100,0);

// redraw the stickman (it will be 100px rightward of the original)
costume1();
```

But if you actually want a version of the stickman with your original fixed-coordinates changed to new "moved" fixed-coordinates, you can send your original stickman into a conversion function that changes the coordinates for you.

To make tracking any stickman easier, add an `x:` & `y:` property to every stickman that indicates how this stickman is offset-X & offset-Y from the original stickman.

**Here's example code and a demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

stickman = {
    x:0,y:0,
    head: [200, 200, 10,0,  2*Math.PI ],
    body: [195, 210, 178, 250],
    rightArm: [192,215,200,230,210,230],
    leftArm: [192,215,178 ,222,178,230],
    rightLeg: [178, 250,190,260,185,275,192, 275],
    leftLeg: [178, 250, 168, 260, 155, 262,153, 268]
} ;

// draw original stickman
costume1(stickman,'black');

// move the stickman's x,y
stickman.x=-50;
stickman.y=-50;

// get the coordinates of the translated stickman
var stickman1={ x:stickman.x, y:stickman.y };
translateStickman(stickman,stickman1);

// draw the moved stickman1
costume1(stickman1,'red');

function costume1(stickman,strokecolor){
// move the canvas origin to the stickman's x,y
context.translate(stickman.x,stickman.y);

context.strokeStyle = strokecolor;
context.beginPath();
//head
context.arc(stickman.head[0], stickman.head[1], stickman.head[2], stickman.head[3], stickman.head[4]);
//body
context.moveTo(stickman.body[0],stickman.body[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.body[2],stickman.body[3]);

//right arm
context.moveTo(stickman.leftArm[0],stickman.leftArm[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftArm[2] ,stickman.leftArm[3]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftArm[4], stickman.leftArm[5]);

//left arm
context.moveTo(stickman.rightArm[0], stickman.rightArm[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightArm[2], stickman.rightArm[3]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightArm[4] , stickman.rightArm[5]);

//left leg
context.moveTo(stickman.rightLeg[0], stickman.rightLeg[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightLeg[2],stickman.rightLeg[3]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightLeg[4] , stickman.rightLeg[5]);
context.lineTo(stickman.rightLeg[6], stickman.rightLeg[7]);


//right leg
context.moveTo(stickman.leftLeg[0], stickman.leftLeg[1]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftLeg[2], stickman.leftLeg[3]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftLeg[4], stickman.leftLeg[5]);
context.lineTo(stickman.leftLeg[6] , stickman.leftLeg[7]);
context.stroke();

// always clean up, unto the last translate 
//    == move the canvas origin back to 0,0
context.translate(-stickman.x,-stickman.y);

}


// create a new stickman with moved coordinates
function translateStickman(stickman,trxStickman){
    var x=stickman1.x;
    var y=stickman1.y;
    var translate=function(a){
        for(var i=0;i<a.length;i+=2){
            a[i]+=x;
            a[i+1]+=y;
        }
    }
    trxStickman.head=stickman.head.slice();
    trxStickman.body=stickman.body.slice();
    trxStickman.rightArm=stickman.rightArm.slice();
    trxStickman.leftArm=stickman.leftArm.slice();
    trxStickman.rightLeg=stickman.rightLeg.slice();
    trxStickman.leftLeg=stickman.leftLeg.slice();
    trxStickman.head[0]+=x;
    trxStickman.head[1]+=y;
    translate(trxStickman.body);
    translate(trxStickman.rightArm);
    translate(trxStickman.leftArm);
    translate(trxStickman.rightLeg);
    translate(trxStickman.leftLeg);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Black == original stickman, Red == moved stickman</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```